# iptables rules break communication between Docker containers

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker, iptables

[`nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) is a Docker container that acts as a reverse proxy to other containers. It uses the Docker API to detect other containers and automatically proxies traffic to them.

I have a simple nginx-proxy setup: (where subdomain.example.com is replaced with my domain)

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=subdomain.example.com kdelfour/cloud9-docker
```

It works with no problem when I have my firewall off. When I have my firewall on, I get a 504 Gateway Time-out error from nginx. This means that I'm able to see nginx on port 80, but my firewall rules seem to be restricting container-to-container and/or Docker API traffic.

I created [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/294), but the creator of nginx-proxy said he had never run into this issue.

These are the "firewall off" rules: (these work)

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

These are my "firewall on" rules: (these don't work)

```
# Based on tutorial from http://www.thegeekstuff.com/scripts/iptables-rules / http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/

# Delete existing rules
iptables -F

# Set default chain policies
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# Allow loopback access
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow inbound/outbound SSH
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow inbound/outbound HTTP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow inbound/outbound HTTPS
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Ping from inside to outside
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
# Ping from outside to inside
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

# Allow outbound DNS
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Allow outbound NTP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 123 -j ACCEPT

# This bit is from https://blog.andyet.com/2014/09/11/docker-host-iptables-forwarding
# Docker Rules: Forward chain between docker0 and eth0.
iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables.rules
```

Why won't the proxy work when I have my firewall on?

Comment: Can you try adding `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` to the end? If that works, then the issue is in the FORWARD chain. If it doesn't work, you know to look in either INPUT or OUTPUT.

Comment: Good thinking. I did as you advised, and it works (i.e. the problem is in the FORWARD chain). I'm going to start researching this, but if the solution pops out to anyone, by all means speak up.

Comment: I think this is a good solution: `iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to advice by Joel C (see the comments above), there was a problem on the FORWARD chain which I fixed like so:

`iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -j ACCEPT`