# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.11.5 running inside docker

Tags: apache, nginx, docker, cxf, gateway

I am running soap web services in Apache Karaf and we are using Apache CXF 2.7.6 and JDK is 1.7.0_80. I am running the following in docker containers on my laptop on Oracle VM Virtual box under Centos 7

- MongoDB
- ActiveMQ
- BlazeDS
- HTTPD
- OpenLDAP
- NGINX
- Nexus

UI which is in Apache Flex calls the below url to login, we get the following error:

http://my_virtual_machine_ip_address/usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl results into 502 Bad Gateway from Nginx

Here, note that Nginx is running inside docker and Apache Karaf which is hosting the soap services is not running inside docker but outside docker, basically running locally.

Could you please let me know what could be done here to solve this issue? Any help in this regard is very much appreciated.

I have also attempted the following to solve this issue:

- Restarting Nginx, httpd and blazeds
- setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true
- setsebool -P httpd_can_network_relay 1
- Rebooting Centos 7 OS

### nginx.conf

```
root@a16807c2c955:/etc/nginx# cat nginx.conf 

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile    on;
tcp_nopush  on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

#gzip  on;

#include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
listen  80 default_server;
listen  [::]:80 default_server;
server_name _;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }



}
}
```

### myapplication.conf

```
    root@a16807c2c955:/etc/nginx/default.d# cat myapplication.conf 
    resolver 127.0.0.1;

    location /crossdomain.xml {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/crossdomain.xml;
    }

        location /blazeds/ {
            proxy_pass      http://ls-blazeds:8089/blazeds/;

            proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;

            error_log       /var/log/nginx/blazeds.error.log;
            access_log      /var/log/nginx/blazeds.access.log;
        }

    location /myapplicationcxf/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-services:8080/cxf/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/myapplication.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/myapplication.access.log;
    }

    location /usermanagementcxf/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-services:8080/cxf/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/usermanagement.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/usermanagement.access.log;
    }

    location /myapplicationtestcxf/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-services:8080/cxf/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/myapplicationtestcxf.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/myapplicationtestcxf.access.log;
    }

    location /myapplicationadapt/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/assets/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/myapplicationadapt.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/myapplicationadapt.access.log;
    }

    location /myapplicationreports/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8083/jasperreportpublisher/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/myapplicationreports.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/myapplicationreports.access.log;
    }

    location /appname/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.access.log;
    }
    location /appname {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.access.log;
    }

    location /APPNAME/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.access.log;
    }
    location /APPNAME {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.access.log;
    }

    location /appnameapp/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.access.log;
    }

    location /myapplication/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.access.log;
    }
    location /myapplication {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.access.log;
    }

    location /Myapplication/ {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.access.log;
    }
    location /Myapplication {
        proxy_pass      http://ls-httpd:8079/;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/appnameapp.access.log;
    }
```

### /etc/hosts file

```
[root@myhostname apache-karaf-2.3.3]# cat /etc/hosts
my_virtual_machine_ip_address ls-blazeds
my_virtual_machine_ip_address ls-services
my_virtual_machine_ip_address ls-mongo
my_virtual_machine_ip_address ls-activemq ls-queue01 ls-queue02
my_virtual_machine_ip_address ls-httpd
my_virtual_machine_ip_address ls-ldap
my_virtual_machine_ip_address ls-nginx
my_virtual_machine_ip_address myhostname
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 myhostname
::1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

### various logs files

```
root@fca3d332c76b:/var/log/nginx# tail -f access.log     
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:12:54:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:12:54:00 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:13:06:54 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:13:06:54 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:13:07:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:54:33 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:54:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
10.0.2.15 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:54:41 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:55:17 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:55:29 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "-"
^C
root@fca3d332c76b:/var/log/nginx# tail -f error.log  
2016/12/02 14:54:33 [error] 9#9: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2016/12/02 14:54:41 [error] 9#9: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.15, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "10.0.2.15"
2016/12/02 14:55:17 [error] 9#9: *10 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "172.17.0.8"
2016/12/02 14:55:29 [error] 9#9: *13 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "172.17.0.1"
^C
root@fca3d332c76b:/var/log/nginx# tail -f usermanagement.access.log 
10.0.2.15 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:49:50 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
10.0.2.15 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:54:14 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
10.0.2.15 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:54:17 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
10.0.2.15 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:54:41 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:55:17 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:55:29 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
10.0.2.15 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:55:37 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
10.0.2.15 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:55:51 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:56:02 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
10.0.2.15 - - [02/Dec/2016:14:56:07 +0000] "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
^C
root@fca3d332c76b:/var/log/nginx# tail -f usermanagement.error.log  
2016/12/05 11:06:14 [error] 7#7: *25 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.2.15, server: _, request: "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.2.15:8080/cxf/UserManagementService?wsdl", host: "10.0.2.15"
2016/12/05 11:37:06 [error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.2.15, server: _, request: "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.2.15:8080/cxf/UserManagementService?wsdl", host: "10.0.2.15"
2016/12/05 13:30:13 [error] 10#10: *4 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.2.15, server: _, request: "GET /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.2.15:8080/cxf/UserManagementService?wsdl", host: "10.0.2.15"
```

### docker inspect network bridge

```
[username@myhostname nginx]# docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "9d6b9700358b5c79e27a29d700c8a6a71e07d15552106901fad6630e9bafdd23",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "18ab8f790aa52111184ce6fd83b22e3c09b89116502dd631a1357ba7f094277c": {
                "Name": "ls-mongo",
                "EndpointID": "9f0cf2d66909316396af4cee466f21ee2b9e5f82eee6e822c4ebab8422910cae",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "24c98a655fecd973f5be8dbd92f3be4b85d7b3516c5e8808fceab3e37f527f4a": {
                "Name": "ls-blazeds",
                "EndpointID": "bc2002dbbdf38703bf2f0b46cf16c28e0f2c12d7ca64dc22070c0723c90ddff3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:08",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.8/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "918d4a4e1dba370f4b232b4e19bb2d6c7e894aea24d96e6fd960a717d8d6001d": {
                "Name": "ls-activemq",
                "EndpointID": "eeb75d2f1b18e9076d8d03a982c349072d32ec8bbcdba0d573270468121c5518",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "93b1bcb9c2d1720f246b212e613ccd1b12f36b078637413147f09d5414302354": {
                "Name": "ls-httpd",
                "EndpointID": "3e910a7c354a4db935d6cf0a7457ba0c81e08492041e912108eda103e644454d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a16807c2c955be35340c7f64f96c100904704e9fee40ca7c7737bcb358972636": {
                "Name": "ls-nginx",
                "EndpointID": "3ebce575049d46101ed50f217d0a61c2ad51a36dca33340cbcef09b00374536c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e1ecc4ac677d7749fb18e78492941d64a71fb80448026f5abf86e70316f3295a": {
                "Name": "nexus",
                "EndpointID": "e3bfa1ab5427636709bddae75a3b7d45f8fb9e80410149f402ed597d18677b92",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f8efa4cb1a28b25895fbf6538c7fa02a0990cf28b8822056e82edbaf13975350": {
                "Name": "ls-ldap",
                "EndpointID": "b0388b3e1f242efdd11bd51e0bf8e31ffb609075583cbea5744a7c3d629f4cbd",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

### flashlogs - UI side

```
12/1/2016 17:38:29.225 [DEBUG] mx.messaging.Channel 'direct_http_channel' channel sending message:
(mx.messaging.messages::HTTPRequestMessage)#0
  body = (Object)#1
  clientId = (null)
  contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  destination = "DefaultHTTP"
  headers = (Object)#2
    DSRemoteCredentials = ""
    DSRemoteCredentialsCharset = (null)
  httpHeaders = (null)
  messageId = "276C2438-DEED-3F9F-5567-BB7752E70224"
  method = "GET"
  recordHeaders = false
  timestamp = 0
  timeToLive = 0
  url = "http://my_virtual_machine_ip_address/usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?"
Warning: HTTP send request error, 12029: /ramplogicadapt/phpFunctions.php
12/1/2016 17:39:11.278 [INFO] mx.messaging.Producer '2304C2EF-FB83-9438-B164-BB7750A0E460' producer acknowledge of 'BAA0601B-0DDD-3FC3-DC17-BB775286490D'.
12/1/2016 17:39:11.281 [ERROR] mx.messaging.Producer '2304C2EF-FB83-9438-B164-BB7750A0E460' producer fault for 'BAA0601B-0DDD-3FC3-DC17-BB775286490D'.
Warning: HTTP send request error, 12029: /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl
12/1/2016 17:39:32.276 [INFO] mx.messaging.Producer '1D4C4F2A-BB9B-28FB-63B1-BB7752DF95B3' producer acknowledge of '276C2438-DEED-3F9F-5567-BB7752E70224'.
12/1/2016 17:39:32.280 [ERROR] mx.messaging.Producer '1D4C4F2A-BB9B-28FB-63B1-BB7752DF95B3' producer fault for '276C2438-DEED-3F9F-5567-BB7752E70224'.
Warning: HTTP send request error, 12002: /usermanagementcxf/UserManagementService?wsdl
12/1/2016 17:39:32.294 [INFO] mx.messaging.Producer 'DDAE8934-5315-F289-CF40-BB7752BCEE4C' producer acknowledge of 'CAC9A8B2-CF6D-3697-03EA-BB7752CF2FB6'.
12/1/2016 17:39:32.295 [ERROR] mx.messaging.Producer 'DDAE8934-5315-F289-CF40-BB7752BCEE4C' producer fault for 'CAC9A8B2-CF6D-3697-03EA-BB7752CF2FB6'.
12/1/2016 17:39:47.598 [DEBUG] mx.rpc.soap.Operation Queueing SOAP operation authenticateAndRegisterLogin
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked me. If you're using the Ethernet bridge created by docker and named docker0, you can set the following rules for forwarding by running the following commands as root:

1. iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
2. iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
3. iptables -I INPUT 1 -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
4. iptables-save
5. reboot command to reboot the machine

Reference:
https://fralef.me/docker-and-iptables.html

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178829/docker-container-not-able-to-ping-host

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24370

[iptables rules break communication between Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833488/iptables-rules-break-communication-between-docker-containers)